# Angular JS2 Http Get Error

Tags: angular, typescript

This is the error I am getting

```
Exception: TypeError: 'caller' and 'arguments' are restricted function properties and cannot be accessed in this context
```

Um using this service class to send a get request as follows

```
@Injectable()
export class LoginService{
    baseUrl:string;
    token:string;
    constructor(private _http: Http, private _loggerService: LoggerService) {
        this.baseUrl = "http://localhost:49454";
        this.token = '';
    }

    private extractData(res: Response) {
        let body = res.json();
        console.log('-------------------------------------------')
        console.log(body);
        console.log('-------------------------------------------')
        return body.data || { };
    }

    private handleError (error: any) {

        console.log('-------------------------------------------')
        console.log('XXX');
        console.log('-------------------------------------------')
        let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
            error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
        console.error(errMsg);
        return Observable.throw(errMsg);
    }

    public pingpong() {

        var test = 'http://localhost:33345/Apple/Bear';

        var sd = this._http.get(test)
            .map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleError);



        return sd;

    }

}
```

Um calling pingpong() method from a ts component

Why Am I getting the above error in this particular class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened because I have not subscribed to get request since its an observable and tried to access it before that .